# PHP: variable value mysteriously set to 0

Tags: php, reference, phpstorm, xdebug

Thanks in advance for your help! I have a situation I'm trying to debug where a variable is mysteriously set to 0.

I know from xdebug (using PHPStorm) that it happens at this specific line:

```
// breakpoint here: $id_key is 'my_entity_id_key'
$e_entity_ids = my_module_fetch_col_keyed($query, $id_key, $created_column);
// breakpoint here: $id_key is 0
```

It's weird, because `$id_key` is not a reference, nor does the function take a reference as a parameter. Also, after the value has changed to `0`, `$id_key` is blue in the variables pane of the debugger.

I've tried making a copy of the variable and using it to pass to the function instead:

```
$id_key2 = $id_key;
$e_entity_ids = my_module_fetch_col_keyed($query, $id_key2, $created_column);
// breakpoint here: $id_key is 0, and so is $id_key2
```

I'm wondering:

1. How could the value of `$id_key` be mysteriously changing to 0?
2. How can I create a copy of `$id_key` so that it's not changed when I pass the copy to `my_module_fetch_col_keyed()`?
3. What does it mean when a variable name is blue in the variables pane in PHPStorm?

When I step into `my_module_fetch_col_keyed()`, there's a line after which $column is mysteriously `0`, as shown:

```
function my_module_fetch_col_keyed($query, $column, $key_column = NULL) {
  try {
    $result = $query->execute();
  }
  catch (Exception $e) {
    return FALSE;
  }

  if (!isset($key_column)) {
    try {
      // breakpoint here: $column is 'my_entity_id_key'
      $column_results = $result->fetchCol($column);
      // breakpoint here: $column is mysteriously 0
    }
    catch (Exception $e) {
      return FALSE;
    }
    return $column_results;
  }

  try {
    $assoc = $result->fetchAllAssoc($key_column);
  }
  catch (Exception $e) {
    return FALSE;
  }

  $keyed = array();
  foreach ($assoc as $key => $result) {
    $keyed[$key] = $result->{$column};
  }

  return $keyed;
}
```

and that `$result->fetchCol()` function is just a one liner that calls `PDOStatement::fetchAll()`:

```
class DatabaseStatementBase extends PDOStatement implements DatabaseStatementInterface {

  [...]

  public function fetchCol($index = 0) {
    return $this->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_COLUMN, $index);
  }

  // function fetchAll() is not overridden from parent PDOStatement

  [...]

}
```

---

**EDIT**: I tried putting `$id_key` as an object property and using the magic `__set()` method to get a backtrace and find out when exactly the variable is changed:

```
class Test {
  private $id_key;
  protected $values = array();
  public function __set($key, $value) {
    if ($key == 'id_key') {
      $b = debug_backtrace();
      "Hello World!";
    }

    if (method_exists(get_parent_class($this), '__set')) {
      return parent::__set($key, $value);
    }

    return $this->values[$key] = $value;
  }
  public function __get($key) {
    return isset($this->values[$key]) ? $this->values[$key] : 1;
  }
}
```

and then I updated my code like so:

```
$e_entity_ids = basic_functions_fetch_col_keyed($query, $test->id_key, $created_column);
```

Everything keeps working the same way it was, and `$test->id_key` evaluates to `my_entity_id_key` before and `0` after. I set breakpoints with in the `__set()` and `__get()` methods, and examined the values when they were called (for example, in the above line the get is called in `basic_functions_fetch_col_keyed($query, $test->id_key, $created_column)`). But, weirdly, THE `__set()` MAGIC FUNCTION WAS NOT CALLED when the value was set to `0`. I'm so lost! Any help would be so appreciated!!

Comment: I'm not sure, but i have a feeling that some try-catch nonsense is happening here. What exception do you get if you remove all of the try-catch blocks from my_module_fetch_col_keyed()?

Comment: bassxzero: I tried removing the try/catches on your suggestion, but nothing changes when I do so. The value is still set to 0. I'm just using the try/catches to catch PDOExceptions and have my code react accordingly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sure does look to me that id_key is being passed by reference.

Some of those PDO libraries are coded in C. It's quite possible that in the innards the variables get corrupted there.

TBF you're passing a string as an argument that expects a numeric value, so from the standpoint of the functions you're using, the new value is the same as the old value (most text strings not containing digits = 0).

Comment: Interesting hypothesis! So in the case that the innards of the PDO function are changing the variable, what's my recourse? I'm using Drupal, so it'll be virtually impossible to use another library for queries. Also, how can I make a copy of `$id_key` so that I'm not passing in the one I want to use later? I thought that the `=` operator automatically made the copy in PHP...

Comment: Now that I think about it, wouldn't all those function calls that are not accepting `$id_key` as a reference be making copies of `$id_key`, so that in changing it somewhere farther down the stack couldn't possibly propagate back up to my original function, or even to `my_module_fetch_col_keyed()`?

Comment: No not at all, if they are receiving by reference then they are more than likely planning to mogrify the variable globally. That's the premise behind why you would pass some things by reference.

Even if it isn't receiving the value by reference, the "glue" between PHP and the C library could be force-typing the variable permanently in order for it to work with the function that expects an integer.